# If(int IDnumvariable == structname[counter].IDnumber) Not working

Tags: c

Im stuck on a situation with my book borrow function, The problem is when i have to compare user entered teacher id with an existing id in the teacherfile.
my id data types for both are integer so i used:

```
    void tborrow() //2.1
{
    int bksb=0;
    int tbid2 =0;   
    struct books book[50];
    struct teachers teach[50];
    int x=0;
    int c=0;
    int i=0;
    int tid=0;
    int tid2=0;
    int tbid=0;
    FILE *teacherp;
    FILE *bkbp;


        teacherp= fopen("TeacherFile.txt", "r+");

    if(teacherp!=NULL)  //Checks if Teacher File was created successfully
    {

        printf("Teacher File Successfully Opened\n\n\n");
        printf("Enter Teacher's ID# :");
        scanf("%d",&tid);


        while(1) // Loop till end of file
        {
            fflush(stdin);////flushes buffer 
            fscanf(teacherp,"%s %d %s %s %d ",teach[i].Teachname,&teach[i].IDnum,teach[i].contactnum,teach[i].Faculty,&teach[i].bksborrowed);
            tid2= tid2 + teach[i].IDnum;
            if (tid == tid2)
            {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Teacher ID Confirmed\n\n");

                    printf("\n\n----Teacher Information-----");  //check if correctly entered
                    printf("\nName: %s ", teach[i].Teachname);
                    printf("\nID #: %d " ,teach[i].IDnum);
                    printf("\nContact #: %s ", teach[i].contactnum);
                    printf("\nFaculty: %s " ,teach[i].Faculty);
                    printf("\nBooks Borrowed: %d " ,teach[i].bksborrowed);
                    printf("\n-----------------------------\n");
                    printf("\nIs your account? 1-Yes  0=No : ");
                    scanf("%d",&c);
                    fflush(stdin);//flushes buffer after scanf

                    if (c==1)//if yes find and borrow book
                            {
                                bksb = bksb+teach[i].bksborrowed;
                            if (bksb < 2)// if teacher has less than 2 books borrowed
                            {
                                    printf("\nThis account currently has %d books borrowed",teach[i].bksborrowed);

                                    bkbp = fopen("BookFile.txt","r+");

                                    if(bkbp!=NULL)  //Checks if Book File was created successfully if yes search for book and borrow
                                    {

                                        printf("Enter Book ISBN # :");
                                        scanf("%d",&tbid);
                                        while(1)
                                        {

                                            fscanf(bkbp,"%s %s %d %d %s %d %d-%d-%d %d-%d-%d ",book[x].Title, book[x].Author, &book[x].Accessionnum, &book[x].ISBN, book[x].Available, &book[x].bid, &book[x].bdate->m, &book[x].bdate->d, &book[x].bdate->y, &book[x].rdate->m, &book[x].rdate->d, &book[x].rdate->y);
                                            tbid2 = tbid2 + book[x].ISBN;
                                            if (tbid == tbid2)
                                            {
                                                printf("\n\n-------Book Information-------");  //check if correct book found
                                                printf("\nTitle: %s", book[x].Title);
                                                printf("\nAuthor: %s" ,book[x].Author);
                                                printf("\nAccession#: %d" ,book[x].Accessionnum);
                                                printf("\nISBN#: %d", book[x].ISBN);
                                                printf("\nAvailability(Y-N): %s" ,book[x].Available);
                                                printf("\nBorrowers ID#: %d ",book[x].bid);
                                                printf("\nBorrow Date: %d-%d-%d ",book[x].bdate->m,book[x].bdate->d,book[x].bdate->y);
                                                printf("\nReturn Date: %d-%d-%d ",book[x].rdate->m,book[x].rdate->d,book[x].rdate->y);  //Prints user entry to screen for confirmation
                                                printf("\n------------------------------\n");
                                                printf("\nIs this the book you are looking for? 1-Yes  0=No : ");
                                                scanf("%d",&c);
                                                fflush(stdin);//flushes buffer after scanf
                                                if (c==1)//if yes print into file
                                                {
                                                    book[x].bid=tid2;
                                                    bksb++;
                                                    teach[i].bksborrowed=bksb;
                                                    printf("\n Book %s has been borrowed by %s %d",book[x].Title,teach[i].Teachname,teach[i].IDnum);
                                                    fclose(bkbp);
                                                    printf("\n\nReturning to previous account");
                                                    _getch();
                                                    break;
                                                    TeacherAcc();
                                                }
                                                /*else
                                                    {
                                                    fclose(bkbp);
                                                    system("cls");
                                                    printf("\nStarting over book borrowing!");
                                                    break;
                                                    tborrow();
                                                     }*/


                                            }
                                            else
                                            //if we encountered the end of the file on the last attempt
                                            //to read data then break out of the read loop
                                            if( feof(bkbp) ) //If end of file is reached break out of loop
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            ++x;
                                        }




                                    }else // if book file failed to open
                                        {
                                        printf("Error!, Restarting Teacher Book Borrowing System. Press Enter to continue");
                                        getchar();
                                        tborrow();
                                        }
                            }else if (teacher[i].bksborrowed == 2) // if teacher has already borrowed 2 books
                                            {
                                                printf("\nThis account already has %d books borrowed",teach[i].bksborrowed);
                                                printf("\nGoing back to previous menu");
                                                _getch();
                                                system("cls");
                                                TeacherAcc();
                                            }

                            }
                            else if (c==0)  //runs the Teacher borrow function if wrong account
                                {
                                    system("cls");
                                    printf("\nRe-Enter Teacher ID!");
                                    tborrow();
                                }




            }else // else if teacher id not found
                    {
                        printf("\nID %d not found, Please re-enter a valid ID \n Press enter to try again",tid);
                        _getch();
                        system("cls");
                        tborrow();
                    }
        if( feof(teacherp) ) //If end of file is reached break out of loop
        {
            break;
        }else

        i++;
        }//end of continuous loop

        fclose(teacherp); //close the file when done
    }   //if file created successfully
    else    //Teacher file failed to load, restarts function to correctly open Teacher
        {
            printf("Error!, Restarting Teacher System. Press Enter to continue");
            getchar();
            system("cls");
        }
    printf("\n\nReturning to previous menu, Press Enter to continue \n");
    fflush(stdin);//flushes buffer so getchar works properly
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    TeacherAcc();
}//borrow function end
```

but it is not correctly comparing or storing the id i read from the file, and the file exists and the has the stored id for tests

attached is the block of code from my teacher borrow function
any help would be appreciated

i was thinking of making the id datatypes char and use strcmp(userentered,struct[count].idnum)

Comment: Why are you doing this: tid2= tid2 + teach[i].IDnum; ?  Where are you doing the comparison (you mentioned in the title)?

Comment: that was meant to store the ID variable that i read from the file to compare with the user entered ID

Comment: Too much code. Present your [mcve]. Also, choose _one_ language. Not two.

Comment: You should remove `tid2= tid2 + teach[i].IDnum;` to be able to compare `tid` and `tid2` correctly, assuming `IDnum` is also `int`. Whenever you execute that line in a loop, user input will be added to the value if `tid2`, which may or may not match with `tid`.

Comment: that was meant to store the ID variable that i read from the file to compare with the user entered ID, i have added the entire function so you may see what im trying to do, 1.Verify that the ID exists in the file 2.If it exists then have them search for a book id 3. if book is found print that record and prompt if they want to borrow it 4.if yes change available to N and store teacher ID from file into bid in books to show who borrowed the book, 5 store the date the book was borrowed in bdate

Comment: can i use      if (tid == teach[i].IDnum)? , i tried it but it skips the while(1) loop and goes to the Cannot find id number else

Comment: TL;DR. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. And that seems to be C. C++ is a different language. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(form the comments)
Remove `tid2= tid2 + teach[i].IDnum;`.

Yes, you can use `if (tid == teach[i].IDnum)`

However, look at what your `while(1)` loop in `tborrow` is doing:

```
while(1)
   read a teacher from the file
   is the teacher the right one?
      yes - do something
      no  - print an error and recursively call tborrow again.
```

Think about how you would do this if you were looking for a teacher by hand in a list on paper - would you look at the first teacher in the list, then give up and start again if it wasn't the right one?

Comment: I get what you are saying, i removed that section of the code. The while(1) loop my intention was for it to run until it reached the end of the file

Comment: would it be best to just use a for loop with a set amount, i am trying to rewrite the while(1) loop so that it increments and then loops again, should i have a static counter?

Comment: You should just continue around the while loop until you find the teacher you are looking for, or hit eof. Once you hit eof you should display the error message.

Comment: Thanks i got it to work with while(! feof(teacherp)) // Loop till end of file